# ActionScript Get crash call stack on iOS

Tags: actionscript, air

I am using Adobe Air3.4 to develop an app on iOS. However, I met a crash only on release version and this crash doesn't happen on debug version. But I cannot get any crash info such as callstack from iOS. Do you have any method to deal with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the offending code in a try/catch statement. Inside the catch code block, you get an [Error](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html) object that you can use to get the stack trace:

```
try
{
    // some code that throws an exception
}
catch (e:Error)
{
    trace(e.getStackTrace())
}
```

If you don't know which code is causing the error, and thus where to add the try/catch statement, you might have some luck with the [UncaughtErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html) -- refer to the examples found at the bottom of the documentation for `UncaughtErrorEvent` that I linked to.

In fact, if you just want a stack trace in general, create a new `Error` object and use its `getStackTrace()` method anywhere in your code.

In addition to checking for errors as above, you should [check the crash logs](http://www.ondemandworld.com/how-to-find-crash-logs/) on your device to see if that provides any additional details.